# c++ array adjust all values by the same amount

Tags: c++, arrays

My question is how to adjust all the values in an array by the same amount so that the smallest value will be zero. I don't know what way to go about it.

Comment: Two passes. Find the minimum. Then subtract it

Comment: So if i get the small value like this than i just subtract?

else if (choice == 4)
  {
   small = num[0];
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
   {
    if (num[i] < small)
     small = num[i];

Comment: Go ahead, show more of your code. I would be thrilled to know how the `choice` is related to processing an array like you describe. You might accidentally end up making a decent [mcve] or even give the impression that you took the [tour] or read [ask].

Comment: I have a menu and choice 4 is the Zero-Based choice that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code which does what you want to do:

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main() {
    int min,i;
    int A[] = {1,5,8,4,3,9,-2,4,-7,6};
    int n = (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));
    min = A[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
     if(A[i]<min)
      min = A[i];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     A[i] = A[i] - min;

}
```

Comment: Thank's i was just missing the A[i] i had it as A[i] - min; thank's a million also you wouldn't know how to reverse the array would ya?